# Clojure-idiomatic way to initialize a Java object

Tags: java, clojure, initialization, idioms

I am trying to find a Clojure-idiomatic way to initialize a Java object. I have the following code:

```
(let [url-connection
      (let [url-conn (java.net.HttpURLConnection.)]
        (doto url-conn
          (.setDoInput true)
          ; more initialization on url-conn
          )
        url-conn)]
  ; use the url-connection
  )
```

but it seems **very** awkward.

What is a better way to create the `HttpURLConnection` object and initialize it before using it later in the code?

**UPDATE**: It seems that `(doto ...)` may come in handy here:

```
(let [url-connection
        (doto (java.net.HttpURLConnection.)
          (.setDoInput true)
          ; more initialization
          ))]
  ; use the url-connection
  )
```

According to the `doto` docs, it returns the value to which it is "doing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the update to my question, here is the answer I came up with:

```
(let [url-connection
        (doto (java.net.HttpURLConnection.)
          (.setDoInput true)
          ; more initialization
          ))]
  ; use the url-connection
  )
```

Maybe someone can come up with a better one.

Comment: What else do you want more? The code is as minimal as you can get.

Comment: @kotarak: I am currently reading "Land of Lisp" by Conrad Barski, MD (very good book!). I am obviously no expert on Clojure, but as I read his examples, I already see how much easier (and efficient) it will be to do the implementations in Clojure, using Maps, Sets, and Vectors instead of just Lists, like in traditional Common Lisp.

Comment: I haven't read Barski's book, but CL does have arrays and hash tables. And I think that, at least at this point, Clojure might have a hard time matching the efficiency of the faster CL implementations.

Comment: But I would also say that Clojure's approach to data types is a lot more consistent than CL's. IMHO that part of Clojure is better designed than the corresponding bits of CL.

Comment: One should not discount the efficiency of the JVM. It does some phenomenal optimizations. Although LISPs have been the subject of many university research projects, I have to think that SUN (SNORCLE) and the Java Community Process have produced a state-of-the-art engine. Clojure gains these "for free". However, http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=clojure&lang2=sbcl backs what you say.

Comment: Yes, Java has become surprisingly fast (at least in the core language.) It wouldn't surprise me if Clojure eventually wound up being "faster" for many things than, say, SBCL.

Comment: Speed is not everything. I think the different literal syntaxes Clojure's introduces, or its persistent data structures are more important. They come with a speed price tag, but so what?

Comment: And don't believe benchmarks too much. I got a data structure with random access written in Clojure down to the speed of a Clojure vector with random access written in Java. Judge on your application, not on ominous micro-benchmarks. They often prove nothing at all. (Of course: Clojure will likely be slower when the algorithm implies mutation. But is that the typical Clojure use case?)

Comment: You're right that for a lot of things being ultra-efficient isn't all that important (though there are times when it is, and I'm glad to see that a lot of effort is going into making Clojure efficient.) I commented mainly because it's possible to get the wrong impression of CL from many books about it. You can program in a very list-oriented way in CL (and this will be pretty inefficient for some things,) but that's not the whole story. Production CL usually looks pretty different.

Comment: And I should add that I certainly agree with you that things like the literal syntax, and particularly the nice sequence abstraction in Clojure can indeed make many things a lot nicer in Clojure. I don't think anyone who has used CL a lot would associate it with the word "perfection" ;). CL has a lot of warts, and though many of them become pretty unimportant once you are experienced with the language, some remain annoying- very much so in some cases. But that said, for me at least, neither Clojure nor CL strictly dominates the other. CL has a lot to offer, despite the warts.

Comment: You can always put some more servers behind your app but you can't put an arbitrary number of people on a project so I think the impotance of  expressivity factor of a language outweights the importance of efficiency in most cases. And by not having to use parentheses for **everything** Clojure is already more usable for me than CL.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that there is no constructor that accepts all the initialization parameters needed, then the way you did it is the only one I know.

The one thing you could do is wrap it all in a function like this:

```
(defn init-url-conn [doInput ...other params..] 
     (let [url-conn (java.net.HttpURLConnection.)]
        (doto url-conn
          (.setDoInput true)
          ; more initialization on url-conn
          )
        url-conn))
```

And call with:

```
(let [url-connection
      (let [url-conn (init-url-con true ...other params..)]
  ; use the url-connection
  )
```

However, this is specific per object and it is really useful only if you are initializing object of that class more than once.

Also you could write a macro that accepts all method names, and params and does this. But, when called, that call wouldn't be much shorter than your first example.

If anyone has a better idea, I'd like to see it, since I was asking myself the same just the other day..

Comment: Yes. And doc for `doto` has a similar example: `(doto (new java.util.HashMap) (.put "a" 1) (.put "b" 2))`