# Clojure macro for calling Java setters based on a map?

Tags: java, macros, clojure, interop, initialization

I'm writing a Clojure wrapper for the Braintree Java library to provide a more concise and idiomatic interface.  I'd like to provide functions to instantiate the Java objects quickly and concisely, like:

```
(transaction-request :amount 10.00 :order-id "user42")
```

I know I can do this explicitly, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314718/clojure-idiomatic-way-to-initialize-a-java-object):

```
(defn transaction-request [& {:keys [amount order-id]}]
  (doto (TransactionRequest.)
    (.amount amount)
    (.orderId order-id)))
```

But this is repetitive for many classes and becomes more complex when parameters are optional.  Using reflection, it's possible to define these functions much more concisely:

```
(defn set-obj-from-map [obj m]
  (doseq [[k v] m]
    (clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeInstanceMethod
      obj (name k) (into-array Object [v])))
  obj)

(defn transaction-request [& {:as m}]
  (set-obj-from-map (TransactionRequest.) m))

(defn transaction-options-request [tr & {:as m}]
  (set-obj-from-map (TransactionOptionsRequest. tr) m))
```

Obviously, I'd like to avoid reflection if at all possible.  I tried defining a macro version of `set-obj-from-map` but my macro-fu isn't strong enough.  It probably requires `eval` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3752276/1226640).

Is there a way to call a Java method specified at runtime, without using reflection?

Thanks in advance!

**Updated solution:**

Following the advice from Joost, I was able to solve the problem using a similar technique. A macro uses reflection at compile-time to identify which setter methods the class has and then spits out forms to check for the param in a map and call the method with it's value.

Here's the macro and an example use:

```
; Find only setter methods that we care about
(defn find-methods [class-sym]
  (let [cls (eval class-sym)
        methods (.getMethods cls)
        to-sym #(symbol (.getName %))
        setter? #(and (= cls (.getReturnType %))
                      (= 1 (count (.getParameterTypes %))))]
    (map to-sym (filter setter? methods))))

; Convert a Java camelCase method name into a Clojure :key-word
(defn meth-to-kw [method-sym]
  (-> (str method-sym)
      (str/replace #"([A-Z])"
                   #(str "-" (.toLowerCase (second %))))
      (keyword)))

; Returns a function taking an instance of klass and a map of params
(defmacro builder [klass]
  (let [obj (gensym "obj-")
        m (gensym "map-")
        methods (find-methods klass)]
    `(fn [~obj ~m]
       ~@(map (fn [meth]
               `(if-let [v# (get ~m ~(meth-to-kw meth))] (. ~obj ~meth v#)))
              methods)
       ~obj)))

; Example usage
(defn transaction-request [& {:as params}]
  (-> (TransactionRequest.)
    ((builder TransactionRequest) params)
    ; some further use of the object
  ))
```

Comment: Without reflection?  Almost certainly not.

Comment: Well, it is possible to translate a map into method calls _without reflection_ using a macro.  I only used reflection upon realizing that the macro couldn't take a symbol holding the map, but only the raw map itself.  I should probably have been more clear in stating that I'd like to avoid reflection at _runtime_, like @joost-diepenmaat describes below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use reflection at compile time ~ as long as you know the class you're dealing with by then ~  to figure out the field names, and generate "static" setters from that. I wrote some code that does pretty much this for getters a while ago that you might find interesting. See https://github.com/joodie/clj-java-fields (especially, the def-fields macro in https://github.com/joodie/clj-java-fields/blob/master/src/nl/zeekat/java/fields.clj).

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. I needed to turn my approach upside-down and rather than taking any map params then trying to reflect at runtime, enumerate setters at compile-time instead.  An added bonus is that only valid params are checked.

Answer (score 1):

The macro could be as simple as:

```
(defmacro set-obj-map [a & r] `(doto (~a) ~@(partition 2 r)))
```

But this would make your code look like:

```
(set-obj-map TransactionRequest. .amount 10.00 .orderId "user42")
```

Which I guess is not what you would prefer :)

Comment: True, this syntax is not ideal and also can't be used by callers of your function.  You would still need to map caller arguments to this syntax somehow.